# RxJava2 - how to emit hashMap value periodically

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I have searched alot on SO and do not think it is duplicate. My problem is straightforward but somehow my solution is not working.

Problem : I have a hashMap and I want to emit value one by one after every 10 seconds.

This is what I have right now which obviously does not yield right value.

```
Observable.fromIterable(factMap.entries)
        .delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe { Timber.i("Abhishek $it") }
```

I tried `interval` as well but I am not sure how to keep a track of which value has been emitted. As you can see I am not experienced in RxJava, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the `.zip` operators with an observable with interval. For example,

```
// RxJava2
Observable.fromIterable(factMap.entries)
        .zipWith(Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), BiFunction<...> { t1, t2 -> t1 })
        .subscribe { Timber.i("Abhishek $it") }
```

Comment: ```Observable.fromIterable(factMap.entries)
            .zipWith(Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), BiFunction<String, String, String> { t1, t2 -> t1 })```
This does not compile, I guess there is no method like this.

Comment: @Abhishek Sharma, what does the warning say? You are passing a hashmap entries and interval, so the bracket should be something like `BiFunction<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, String>, Long, MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, String>>` instead of `BiFunction<String, String, String>`. Also make sure that you are using `io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction`.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake there. Working fine. Accepting your answer. Thanks for your help.